# CEFSharp devtool blinking

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium, cefsharp

I'm currently working on an app using CEFSharp.WinForms (v92.0.260) and i'm facing an issue with the devtools.
When i use the ShowDevTools method, the dev tool window appears as intended but the application start to 'blink' between the browser window and the dev tool window (like if i pressed alt tab 3 time each second). This behaviour is independant of the page loaded.

This strange blinking stops sometimes when i move/maximize/resize one of the two window (couldn't figure a pattern to fix it each time).

I tried a lot of window configuration but nothing changed (window topmost, resizable, maximized etc..) and this strange behaviour occures only when the devtool is displayed.

Comment: Does the problem reproduce with the minimum example? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample should be able to open DevTools through the menu in the WinForms example.

Comment: I tried on the minimal example (CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms.net472) and i can reproduce the blinking by putting a b.ShowDevTools(); in the OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged() method. The blinking behaviour does not occures in the sample when i call the ShowDevTools through the InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired method but in my solution this continue to happen :(

Answer (score 1):

After some more tests.. it seems that the issues comes from the chaining of the browser.Focus method and browser.ShowDevTools methods. If i put a small delay (1sec) betweek the call of the two methods, the blinking between the two window does not occures in both the minimal example and my solution.

Comment: I encountered the same issue when updating to from v83 to v94.  Fixed it by wrapping ShowDevTools() within an invoke (this.Invoke((Action)(() => {                    chromeBrowser.ShowDevTools();  }));

Comment: Can you please let me know what is "this"?

Comment: I guess it's the Form itself